# Java serial port Problem

Tags: java, serial-port, macos

I am trying to turn the relay on/off but so far i couldnt succeed. I tried Coolterm program to see if the drivers were installed correctly and yes it worked and i was able to turn it on/off via GUI. However I have problem to send the command via java to turn the relay on..

Communication Parameters:
8 Data, 1 Stop, No Parity
Baud rate : 9600

Commands:
OFF command: FF 01 00 (HEX) or 255 1 0 (DEC)

ON command: FF 01 01 (HEX) or 255 1 1 (DEC)

My code is below:

```
public class Application {

InputStream in;
OutputStream out;
String dataHex = "FF 01 01";

void connect(String portName) throws Exception {

CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
System.out.println(portIdentifier);
CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);
System.out.println(commPort);
SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
System.out.println(serialPort);
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

this.in = serialPort.getInputStream();
this.out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

System.out.println(dataHex.getBytes());
out.write(dataHex.getBytes());

System.out.println("end");


}

InputStream getIn() {
return this.in;
}

OutputStream getOut() {
return this.out;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws QTException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
Application app = new Application();
try {

app.connect("/dev/tty.usbserial-A400953X");

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}


}
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which Java libraries are you using?

Comment: import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import quicktime.QTException;
import gnu.io.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

ignore Qt library, i forgot to delete it since i was working with it  before..

Comment: The last time I did serial port development, I did some simple testing of my application by removing the device I was communicating with. So instead of testing your app by waiting for it to trip the relay, test your app by having another application listen on the same TTY and see if your app is sending the right commands. After you've proven your app sends the right commands, then introduce the actual serial device.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is current sending the String "FF 01 01" which is 8 bytes long in an ascii compatible encoding. This seems pretty unusual, I guess your gadget is really expecting 3 bytes as in the following code:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x01};

out.write(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
byte[] array = { -1, 1, 1 };
out.write(array);
```

instead of

```
out.write(dataHex.getBytes());
```